# Exclude graph values above certain point

Tags: graph, graphite

I would like to ensure that when looking at my web-server response time graphs I can see a good level of detail from 0-5k on the scale of my graph. However occasionally there are metrics above the 5k (File downloads) mark which then increase the scale of the graph making it difficult to see what is going on around the regular range of values.

How do I exclude metric values from being plotted that are above 5k? Bearing in mind I do not want metrics themselves to be excluded.

Or perhaps the best thing to do would be to scale down the high points with log, but then I loose the actual scale information, which is quite useful at a glance.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Graphite Documentation](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/):

http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/render_api.html#ymax

> *Default: The highest value of any of the series displayed*
>
> Manually sets the upper bound of the graph. Can be passed any integer
>   or floating point number.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> &yMax=0.2345
> ```

Looks like `yMax` parameter was only a suggestion at one point. Reported to be strictly enforced as of 0.9.5. For more: https://bugs.launchpad.net/graphite/+bug/412663

Also, from: http://graphite.wikidot.com/url-api-reference

> `yMin` and `yMax` set the minimum and maximum y-values for the generated
>   image. A good use of these parameters would be `min=0&max=100` when the
>   value you are graphing is a percentage.

---

Some other finds. Not sure if they're entirely relevant; might be helpful.

**graphite-graph-dsl:** A small DSL to describe graphite graphs
https://github.com/behrendsj/graphite-graph-dsl

- Added ability to define the right y-axis min and max values:
   https://github.com/behrendsj/graphite-graph-dsl/commit/11e146b0b3eb82faa7c1f5db5af324c81db66144

**graphene:** Graphene is a realtime dashboard & graphing toolkit based on D3 and Backbone.
https://github.com/jondot/graphene

- Define `yMax` support: https://github.com/jondot/graphene/pull/33

Comment: Thanks, great answer - I did not find this in the docs, as I was looking for a function rather than a property!